# Erro ao rodar flutter pub get no projeto

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I'm getting this error:
`` The `device_info_plus` plugin requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2. Follow the steps onhttps://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration and re-run this command. ``

I have a fully updated project and all the code settings are in accordance with the migration changes that are present in the link that is in the error. I can't run the project and I can't find another solution on the web. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question's title to make it in English.

Comment: The title "Error running flutter pub get in project" already exists.